# How do I print the dynamic location for each user using MYSQL

Tags: php, dynamic, location

The code

```
<?
if($items["User"]["city"]!=""){
    echo " ". $items["User"]["city"];
} else {
    echo " Unknown Location";
}
?>
```

IS working on this page `http://www.u.neighborrow.com/requests/view/2183` DISPLAYING THE CORRECT LOCATION = HOUSTON

I PUT THE SAME CODE ON items/view to dynamically pull location... 
so I modified REQUESTS to ITEMS and put the same code [here](http://www.u.neighborrow.com/items/view/103595)

but it's not finding the right data.

How can I get UNKNOWN LOCATION to display the CITY in the users table of the owner of the item?

Comment: Your question is not entirely clear. Please provide more information explain your current code and need.

Comment: Can you actually show the results of `print_r($items)` in both of the pages (requests and items) and post it here? That would be helpful.

Comment: Is this CakePHP?  If that's the case, the `Item` model probably just doesn't have an association called `User` like the `Request` model does.  Your job would be to add that association, or figure out what it *is* called.  `Owner` for instance.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some steps you need to apply

- Debug the the result
- Identify the difference
- Modify accordingly

These simple steps will get you far in the world of computer science

Answer (score 0):

I think you should know what has already been put in the array.you can use the print_r or var_dump functions.
then try to go through the array use for or foreach .

Answer (score 0):

I notice the first URL shows the location "houston" in the description text. The second URL attempts to show location in the title, showing Location Unknown instead. The second URL **does** show a location "NYC" in the description text.

It may be your framework/library does not have the 'city' datum available at the time it is printing the title.